# Facebook page insights via API

Tags: api, facebook, analytics

I would like to access the insights of a Facebook page via the API. It is very well possible to obtain the insights of a Facebook app via the graph API, but I cannot find something similar for Facebook pages. Am I missing something?

Specifically, I am looking for stats such as total users, active users, posts, etc, preferrably over time as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Insights`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights) table docs say it is possible to retrieve metrics for all pages that are owned by currently logged in user after requesting `read_insights` extended permission. I think after that graph insights should work (`/<page_id>/insights?access_token=...`). If not then you probably need to use FQL (they have example in docs for getting page metrics).

Comment: It's neccesary to be logged in when using FQL too?

Answer (score 0):

The trailing slash is breaking this query.  If you remove it you will see insights if permissions are correct, or "Only administrators of applications, pages, and domains can retrieve Insights" if not.